# ng serve makes vite server as a backend instead of server.ts in angular 17 ssr?

Tags: angular, vite, server-side-rendering, angular17

i have been trying to make http request in the new angular 17 with server side rendering using the command `ng serve` but i realised its http req not going to work in the development because `server.ts` file not serving the front end (vite serves...).
which makes me wonder! what the point of adding ssr but can't interact with it???
now how can i make vite runs the server.ts instead?

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/next-gen-teacher",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "browser": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": [
          "zone.js"
        ],
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          "src/manifest.webmanifest"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [],
        "server": "src/main.server.ts",
        "prerender": true,
        "ssr": {
          "entry": "server.ts"
        }
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "500kb",
              "maximumError": "1mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "2kb",
              "maximumError": "4kb"
            }
          ],
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "serviceWorker": "ngsw-config.json"
        },
        "development": {
          "optimization": false,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "buildTarget": "next-gen-teacher:build:production"
        },
        "development": {
          "buildTarget": "next-gen-teacher:build:development"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "development"
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "next-gen-teacher:build"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "polyfills": [
          "zone.js",
          "zone.js/testing"
        ],
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          "src/manifest.webmanifest"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": []
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have a related issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77600050/how-to-debug-angular-17-server-code-with-a-new-build-system. I ended up with running two commands in two terminals: `npm run watch` and `npm run serve:ssr:project-name`, where "project-name" is the name of your project. But your have to manually rerun the second command after each code change.

Comment: @Nazir i have done something similar `ng build`  followed by `npm run dev:ssr`  but still not very helpful

Comment: @Nazir  i used nodemon npm package for 2nd command somewhat became helpful but still req  and res body not able to inject them   with server.ts