# How to debug angular 17 server code with a new build system?

Tags: angular

Befor v17 I could run `npm run dev:ssr -- --inspect` and then debug server code in a Node.js inspector. But now the command `npm run dev:ssr` does not exists due to a new build system https://angular.io/guide/esbuild, and when I try to run `ng serve --inspect` it throws an error: `Error: Unknown argument: inspect`.
Any ideas?

Comment: There are anohter commands in `package.json`: ```"watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development"``` and ```"serve:ssr:ng-17": "node dist/ng-17/server/server.mjs"```. You can add an `--inspect ` flag to the second command like this ```"serve:ssr:ng-17": "node --inspect dist/ng-17/server/server.mjs"``` and debug server code in a node inspector, but it is not very convinient since you have to run two commands in two terminals and rerun the second command manually after each code change.
Is there a better way?